# After changing my Rails Version to 6.0.3.5 from 6.1.3 for Heroku. I have got a Runtime Error after running Rails S

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

[image]

When deploying basic app for the first time to Heroku I had to change my Rails Version to 6.0.3.5 from 6.1.3 because Heroku wasn't working on Rails 6.1.3. After changing the version to 6.0.3.5 in the Gemfile and running "bundle"  and "bundle update". I am getting a Runtime error as attached. I am  a beginner, help to right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your `config/application.rb` file. You will find there following line:

```rb
config.load_defaults 6.1
```

Rails are trying to load default configuration for version 6.1, but it is not there on rails 6.0.

Just change this line to:

```rb
config.load_defaults 6.0
```

and it should work unless you are using more stuff from 6.1 in your app.

Comment: Thanx I did it but I now I get a NoMethodError as attached. https://imgur.com/GDULGq9

Comment: If you are trying to downgrade application generated with rails 6.1 to 6.0, there will be lots of thing like these. What was wrong at the first place? Why it didn't run on heroku? I think you should try to figure out this first because it also might happen that you will not fix anything by the downgrade. That error tells you about undefined method `load_server` in your `config.ru` file. It was introduced in rails 6.1. Try to remove (or comment) the line with that call.

Comment: Yeah I uncommented that line but my home page is not running so I went back to rails 6.1 and going to deploy it and see what's wrong.

Comment: I think that is the right course of action

Comment: I deployed to Heroku without changing the Rails Version and it worked. Only thing home page isn't coming up. I need to upgrade Ruby 2.7.2. Thankyou for your help.